# Model-First Entity Framework Max String Length of 4000

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

For a project I have a SQL Server CE 3.5 database.

It is accessed / created through entity framework with the model-first approach.

Now I have some `String` typed columns in my EDMX, which have the max length specified.

```
EDMX declaration
<Property Name="Description" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="Max" />
```

The generated code (`*.sqlce` file) shows that from the max-length string column in the model a `nvarchar(4000)` column is generated.

```
.edmx.sqlce file (sql to create the database)
[Description] nvarchar(4000)  NULL,
```

This is not long enough for the strings that shall be stored in these columns.

In some code-first approach solutions to this issue I have seen that the `ntext` datatype can help, because it does not have the 4000 chars limit.

How can this be achieved in a model-first environment?

Comment: have you tried Type="nvarchar(max)" ?

Comment: @tschmit007 I do not see where to put this in the model. I only have the "String" type there. Can you give me more information please?

Comment: @tschmit007 I have tried to edit this in the xml editor for the model.edmx. The model can not be opened afterwards, so I cannot generate the edmx.sqlce file.

Comment: Have you tried Type="ntext"? (nvarchar(MAX) is not available with SQLCE)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. The model cannot be opened afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Add FixedLength="false" - so:

```
<Property Name="Text" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" />
```

Then it is generated as ntext using the standard template

Of course you must connect to a SQL Server Compact database file when the wizard comes up for this to work. You can install my SQL Server Compact Toolbox to enable this in VS 2012 or newer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I edit that? Using "String" as in your example leads to "Error 8 Error 40: The Type String is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only PrimitiveTypes can be used without qualification." and using FixedLength as you suggest leads " Error 8 Error 64: Facet 'FixedLength' must not be specified for type 'nvarchar'."

Comment: I just used the GUI property editor for the property in question

Comment: Updated my reply with screenshot and clarifications

Comment: These are exactly the settings that I have chosen. In the Storage section of the EDMX file I see still nvarchar for storage. In the generated SQL there is still nvarchar. Will try the SQL Compact Toolbox you mentioned.

Comment: Do you connect to a SQL Server Compact database file, and which version of VS are you using? And I have not done any manual editing of my EDMX, pls do not do that

Comment: I tried it with a connection before doing all of that. Normally I connect at the time I execute the SQL to create the database. This has not changed anything. It is VS 2010. I manually edited the EDMX just because I do not see any way to do it else. I need this change as the customers need to store larger strings. Editing the generated SQL works, but I do not believe this is the favored way of doing that.

Comment: Which EF version, I am using 6,1,1? It could be a bug that was fixed in newer versions...

Comment: Very good hint, I will check that. (Will take some time, I am not near my computer right now). I am quite sure it is a 4.x version, which ships with the 4.0 framework.

Comment: This is a very good reason to migrate the software I believe.